# Pandas internals - "Index labels must be unique"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The [Pandas Internals documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/internals.html) (v1.2.4) states

> In pandas there are a few objects implemented which can serve as valid
> containers for the axis labels:
>
> - Index: the generic “ordered set” object, an ndarray of object dtype assuming nothing about its contents. The labels must be hashable (and
>   likely immutable) and unique. Populates a dict of label to location in
>   Cython to do O(1) lookups.

Clearly dataframe indexes do not need to be unique:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({10, 20, 30}, index=['a','b','b'])
df.index
# Index(['a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Why does the documentation quoted above state that labels in an index must be unique?

Comment: You can help update the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In pandas there are a few objects implemented which can serve as ***valid*** containers for the axis labels

The keyword here is ***valid***, Pandas allows you to create non-unique indexes, but there will be some functions with errors. Just because it allows something, doesn't make it "valid".

The `set_index()` function has a keyword `verify_integrity` that can be used to make the function error when the index wouldn't be "valid".